# Slider on a timer JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, timer, slider

I have got images from a database but I am having issues with the slider timer so that when it reaches the last radio input it goes back to start rather than go on to the next one which is empty and then back to the start.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

    require 'includes/connect.php';
    include('includes/functions.php');
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM images");
    $query2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM images");
    $query3 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM images");
    $query4 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM images");
    $select = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM images");

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Triology - Multi Sport Solutions </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <script src ="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/script2.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/scroll.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function slider(){

            <?php 

            $a = 1;
            $b = 1;
            $count = mysqli_fetch_array($select);       




            echo "  
                var count = 1;

                    setInterval(function(){
                    if(count > ". $count['total'] ."){
                        count = 1;
                    }";

                    while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($query4)){
                            echo "
                                if(document.getElementById(\"slide". $a++ . "\").checked){
                                    count = ". $b++.";

                                    count ++;

                                }";

                    }
                    echo "
                    document.getElementById(\"slide\" + count++).checked = true;
                    }, 5000);";

            ?>
        }
    </script>


    <title>CMS - Admin</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header holding the navigation and the logo-->
    <div id ="accountBar" style = "color: white;">You are logged in! Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?><a class = "logout" href = "logout.php">Log out</a></div>

        <div id = "header">
        <div id = "logo"></div>
            <div id = "nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "store.php">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "services.php">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "about.php">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "https://twitter.com/triologyuk"><img src = "images/twitterLogo.png" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href = "https://www.facebook.com/triologyuk"><img src = "images/facebookLogo.png" /></a></li>
                    <li><a onclick = "showSearch();"><img src = "images/searchButton.png" /></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id = "searchBar" class = "hide">
                    <ul>
                        <header>Search...</header>
                        <li>
                            <form method = "post" action = "searchBrand.php">
                                <select name = "brand">
                                    <option value = "">Search by Brand</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM brands");
                                        while($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    ?>

                                    <option value ="<?php echo $cat['brand']?>"><?php echo $cat['brand']?></option>
                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = ""></input>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <form autocomplete="off" method = "post" action = "searchResults.php" size = "40" maxlength = "50">
                                <input id ="search" type = "text" name = "search" placeholder = "Search products..."/>
                                <input style = "top: 2px;" type = "submit" name = "submit" value = ""></input>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="scrollToTop"><img src = "images/top.png"/></a>
        </div>


        <div id = "mainWrapper">
                <a id = "edit"href = "addImage.php">Add/ Delete Image</a>
                <!--Slider-->
                <div id ="retulLogo"></div>
                <div id="slider">
                <input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" selected="false">
                    <?php 
                    $b = 2;
                    while($post3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){
                        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"slider\" id=\"slide" . $b++ . "\" selected=\"false\">";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div id="slides">
                        <div id="overflow">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <?php if($query->num_rows == 0){
                                            echo "<td colspan = \"2\">There's no images in the database</td>";
                                        } else {
                                            while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                                                echo "<img src=\"data:image;base64," . $post['image'] . "\">";
                                            }
                                        }   
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    $a = 1;
                        while($post2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){ echo "<label for=\"slide". $a++ . "\"></label>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>

                <!--Menu holding swimming, running, swimming and events-->
                <div id = "menuWrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div id = "bikeIco"></div>
                            <header>Cycling Products</header>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id = "swimIco"></div>
                            <header>Swimming Products</header>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div id = "runIco"></div>
                            <header>Running products</header>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <!--New products, special offer and featured-->
                <div id = "productsNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a onclick = "featuredProducts()" id = "featured" class = "active">Featured Products</a></a></li>
                        <li><a onclick = "newProducts()" id = "new" class = "notActive">New Products</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick = "specialOffers()" id = "special" class = "notActive">Special Offers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id = "productsWrapper">    
                    <div id ="catWrapperF" class = "active">
                        <?php getFeatured();?>  
                    </div>
                    <div id ="catWrapperN" class = "notActive">
                        <?php getNewProducts();?>   
                    </div>
                    <div id ="catWrapperS" class = "notActive">
                        <?php getSpecialOffers();?> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Logos footer-->
                <div id = "logosFooter">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src = "images/logo1.png"/><li>
                        <li><img src = "images/logo2.png"/><li>
                        <li><img src = "images/logo3.png"/><li>
                        <li><img src = "images/logo4.png"/><li>
                        <li><img src = "images/logo5.png"/><li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

        <!--Footer-->
        <div id = "footer">
            <ul id = "contact">
                <header>Contact us</header>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src = "images/address.png"></td><td>Ellerton on Swale,<br> Richmond North Yorkshire, DL10 6AP</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src = "images/email.png"></td><td><a href = "contact.php">Contact us by Email<a/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ul>
            <ul id = "contact">
                <header>Opening Times</header>
                <table>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>Monday:</td>    
                        <td>Tuesday:</td>   
                        <td>Wednesday:</td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thursday:</td>
                        <td>Friday:</td>
                        <td>Saturday:</td>
                        <td>Sunday:</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ul>
            <ul id = "developer">Web Designer/ Developer Ryan North</ul>
        </div>      
    <?php

         } else {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
     ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding properly what you want.... but try this?

```
 if(count >= ". $count['total'] .") ... (rest of code)
```